# sending parameters down to MVC4 action from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, parameters, action

I get an exception that I was not expecting when I attempt to use my site with firefox and chrome...

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditEncounterReturnPage(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)'
```

Now, the same call will work just fine in IE 9... I will actually get values down to my actions, with little hitch at all.

This is the jquery I use to send my parameters down...

```
            ondblClickRow: function (id) {
                var pageInfo = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'page');
                var rowSZ = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum');
                debugger;
                var dummyURL = '@Url.Action("EditEncounterReturnPage", "EditEncounter", new { encounterId = "-2", popId = (int)TempData["POPULATIONID"], page = "-3", rowSize = "-4" })';
                dummyURL = dummyURL.replace("-2&amp;", id + "&");
                dummyURL = dummyURL.replace("-3&amp", pageInfo + "&");
                dummyURL = dummyURL.replace("-4&amp", rowSZ + "&");
                var path = dummyURL;
                window.location = path;                    
            }
```

Now I don't have nullable parameters in the action that I am calling...

```
    public ActionResult EditEncounterReturnPage(int encounterId, int popId, int page, int rowSize) { ...
```

I have to be missing something.  I am setting up my parameters incorrectly?

```
/EditEncounter/EditEncounterReturnPage?encounterId=1900&popId=2&amp;page=2&;rowSize=-4
```

I think I might know what it is... I have 2& in the url I need to replace that as well...

Comment: Please log out (e.g with an `alert(path)`) the `path` variable both in IE9 where it is working and FF where it is not and post the urls here.

Answer (score 1):

your parameter of page in of data type int and you are passing page = "-3" in double quotes which tells jqgrid that it is string.  you need to remove double quotes and just pass -3 like the following and this should work

```
        ondblClickRow: function (id) {
            var pageInfo = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'page');
            var rowSZ = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum');
            debugger;
            var dummyURL = '@Url.Action("EditEncounterReturnPage", "EditEncounter", new { encounterId = "-2", popId = (int)TempData["POPULATIONID"], page = -3, rowSize = "-4" })';
            dummyURL = dummyURL.replace("-2&amp;", id + "&");
            dummyURL = dummyURL.replace("-3&amp", pageInfo + "&");
            dummyURL = dummyURL.replace("-4&amp", rowSZ + "&");
            var path = dummyURL;
            window.location = path;                    
        }
```

Comment: But I have the same thing for encounter ID... I need to make sure I get rid of the ; in my strings.  Because It only asks for null parameters after encounter and pop Id's

Comment: page is built in jqgrid for paging purposes of grid, it expects it to be int, so try without double quotes and it should work, if it does the same then post full code and I will try to debug it.

Comment: I wanted it to be strings so I can replace the strings with the values of the parameter.

Comment: i suggest you change the name of the parameter from page to something else, since page is specifically in jqgrid for paging

Comment: well, I got it to work.  I was forgetting to add a ';' to my replace strings